# Finding the two highest numbers based on input

Tags: java

I'm tasked in completing a program where the user enters student names and their scores. In the end, the program should output the two students with the highest scores, however I'm only able to output the student with the highest score.

```
public class StudentScores
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
    int numStudents = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
    String Student1 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
    int Score1 = input.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents - 1; i++) 
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
        String Student = input.next();
        System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
        int Score = input.nextInt();

        if (Score > Score1) 
        {
            Student1 = Student;
            Score1 = Score;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Student1 + "'s score is " + Score1);
}}
```

The thing I'm unsure about is how to figure out how to get a Student2 and Score 2 in the mix based on user input. I'd like to use arrays but I must use loops so this is where I'm stumped.

Comment: Also, it's recommended you use the Java convention of naming variables in "camelCase", as `score1` and `student1`, to avoid confusion with class names.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html

Comment: Good idea @iamnotmaynard - and thank you for the link. I believe I have figured out my issue. I was using an Else If statement before and was getting reverse results but now I see my problem. Thank you. I also want to add I cannot use arrays. Thank you for the ideas but as is stated above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (Score > Score1) 
{
    Student2 = Student1;
    Score2 = Score1;
    Student1 = Student;
    Score1 = Score;
}
else if (Score > Score2)
{
    Student2 = Student;
    Score2 = Score;
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is what I originally had, but now I think I understand how to use it. I was getting reverse results and I see exactly why now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the students in an array and then sort the array and return the first two.

or if you only want to store the highest two scores then you would need some nested comparators.

```
if (score > score2) {
    if (score > score1) {
        student2 = student1;
        score2 = score1;
        student1 = student;
        score1 = score;
    } else {
        student2 = student;
        score2 = score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, bumping out of first place should bump into second place.  Given scores in order [1,2,3,4], your code will return 4 for Score1 but 1 for Score2.

Answer (score 1):

You will need another pair of variables `Student2`, `Score2` in order to track the second student. You may initialize both scores to an value lower than the minimum (for instance, if scores range from 0 to 10, you may initialize them in -1);

```
String Student1 = "none", Student2 = "none";
int Score1 = -1, Score2 = -1;


for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) 
{
    System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
    String Student = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
    int Score = input.nextInt();

 if (Score > Score1) 
    {
        Student2 = Student1;
        Score2   = Score1;
        Student1 = Student;
        Score1   = Score;
    }
    else if (Score > Score2) {            
        Student2 = Student;
        Score2   = Score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Acutally it should be (i<numStudents)

Comment: That logic is incorrect.  If Score1 is meant to be the highest score, then bumping a student out of it should bump them *into* Score2 (as in my answer).  If, on the other hand, Score2 is meant to be the highest score, then this will misorder them.

Comment: This works well, but in this case I had to remove the "-1" in order for it to process each student. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Arrays.sort() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) in Java. The proper way to do it would be to create a "Student" object with a name and a score. It would look something like this:

```
public class Student implements Comparable {
     private int score;
     private String name;

     public Student(String name, int score)
     { // Constructor Code }
```

Make the object implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which means writing a [compare method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10). When you've sorted your array of Students, print the top two names in the array.

Answer (score 1):

For easy sorting (which will work for any amount of students) I suggest that the class `Student` handles both the score and the name which implements `Comparable<Student>`. Then you'll have to write the `compareTo(Student student)` method which should return 1 if score of `this` is bigger than that of `student`, 0 if they're equal and -1 otherwise. Then you can use `Collections.sort()` (for `Collections`, i.e `ArrayList`) and `Arrays.sort()`.

Answer (score 1):

A `TreeMap<Integer, String>` can be useful here, which is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys:

```
TreeMap<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
int numStudents = input.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
    System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
    String Student = input.next();
    System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
    int Score = input.nextInt();
    map.put(Score, Student);
}

Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry1 = map.pollLastEntry();
Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry2 = map.pollLastEntry();
System.out.println("Highest score: " + entry1.getKey());
System.out.println("Highest scorer: " + entry1.getValue());
System.out.println("Second highest score: " + entry2.getKey());
System.out.println("Second highest scorer: " + entry2.getValue());
```

Finding third, fourth etc. highest score/scorers will be much easier with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
package deneme;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HighestTwoScore {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number of student: ");
        int numberOfStudents = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the Students name and score: ");
        String name1 = input.next();
        int score1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter the Students name and score: ");
        String name2 = input.next();
        int score2 = input.nextInt();

        int controlScore = score1;
        String controlName = name1;
        if (score1 < score2) {
            score1 = score2;
            score2 = controlScore;
            name1 = name2;
            name2 = controlName;
        }

        int i = 0;
        while (i < numberOfStudents - 2) {
            System.out.print("Enter the Students name and score: ");
            String name = input.next();
            int score = input.nextInt();

            if (score > score1) {
                score2 = score1;
                name2 = name1;
                score1 = score;
                name1 = name;

            } else if (score > score2) {
                score2 = score;
                name2 = name;
            }

            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("Top student1 " + name1 + "'s score is " + score1);
        System.out.println("Top student2 " + name2 + "'s score is " + score2);
    }

}
```

Comment: (some explanation would be nice... )[http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoLargestNumbers{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter number: ");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int firstLarge = 0, secondLarge = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            int num = input.nextInt();

            if (num >= firstLarge) {
                secondLarge = firstLarge;
                firstLarge = num;
            }

            if (num > secondLarge && num < firstLarge)
                secondLarge = num;

        }

        System.out.println("First large number is: " + firstLarge);
        System.out.print("Second large number is: " + secondLarge);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are checking number is greater than secondLarge and then if it is true you are assigning firstlarge as num. I think your logic is wrong. Example: secondLarge is 20 and firstLarge is 30 and num is 25. You will be making secondlarge as 30 and firstlarge as 25. after that in the next iteration if the num is 27, you ignore it because secondlarge is 30. so the first and second large will still be 30 and 25 instead of 30 and 27

Comment: Sorry, The commends modified.